# how many array elements can be processed in 4.5 ms?

Tags: assembly

I'm practicing some problems and have some trouble understanding some. The answer to the following question is 865384.0. But I don't understand how they got to that. Does anyone understand and wouldn't mind explaining?

Suppose you have a RISC machine with a 2.5 GHz clock (i.e., the clock ticks 2.5 billion times per second). This particular computer uses an instruction cache, a data cache, an operand fetch unit, and an operand store unit. The instruction set includes simple instructions with the following timings:

```
set  reg, immed  1.0 clock cycle
loop label       6.0 clock cycles
add reg, immed   1.0 clock cycle 
add reg, reg     2.0 clock cycles 
load reg, mem    4.0 clock cycles
```

Assume that the following code fragment is used to sum the element of a numeric array. If the initialization code has already executed (i.e. the SET instructions have already finished execution) how many array elements can be processed in 4.5 ms? Round your answer to the nearest integer. Recall that 1 ms = 0.001 seconds. Also assume that there are no physical memory limitations, implying that the array can be as large as desired.

```
   set   r1, 0        ;initialize sum
   set   r2, MAX_SIZE ;initialize loop counter
   set   r3, @list    ;initialize array pointer
more:
   load  r4, \textrm{5.0}      ;fetch current list element
   add   r1, r4       ;add current list element
   add   r3, 4        ;move array pointer to next element
   loop  more         ;auto-decrement r2, jump to more if r2 != 0
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope of the FAQ. It appears to be a theoretical question.

Comment: It seems fairly concrete to me. Given these parameters and a known instruction set, how does one determine how many times this loop can process in a given time frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 2.5GHz Processor can do 2,500,000,000 cycles per second

In 4.5ms, processor can do 2,500,000,000 * 0.0045 cycles
= 11,250,000 cycles

Each iteration of the loop requires 13 cycles to execute. You only count the last four instructions after the label *more* where it's looping to:

```
- load: 4 cycles
- first add (register to register): 2 cycles
- second add (immediate to register): 1 cycle
- loop: 6 cycles
```

11,250,000 cycles available / 13 cycles per iteration = 865,385 iterations

Comment: much appreciated. Thank you.